# bpmn.io / bpmn-js expose optional modules

Tags: javascript, module, bpmn, bpmn.io

The bpmn-js (and diagram-js) allows to include optional modules, that augment the current functionality.

**Example:** [Modeler.js (from line 174, commit [ae96f37][1](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js/commit/ae96f3714dcd7a87bcbd165fe599a0999ebba139))](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js/blob/master/lib/Modeler.js#L174)

```js
Modeler.prototype._interactionModules = [
  // non-modeling components
  require('diagram-js/lib/navigation/movecanvas'),
  require('diagram-js/lib/navigation/touch'),
  require('diagram-js/lib/navigation/zoomscroll')
];
```

Now in order to get an overview about the certain modules, I currently have to look at the folders of the both modules (`bpmn-js`, `diagram-js` in `node_modules`) to see the whole list of possible modules:

**[Example 1:](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js/tree/master/lib/features)** `bpmn-js/lib/features/*` (commit: [b03014f](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js/commit/b03014fc2c83b8acd982d407137617e3df36c92c))

**[Example 2:](https://github.com/bpmn-io/diagram-js/tree/master/lib)** `diagram-js/lib/*` (commit: [7956c81](https://github.com/bpmn-io/diagram-js/commit/7956c81c632f70fabb524bde8147c609229ff02b))

However, if I want to have a more modular Modeler design (e.g. add / remove functionality, depending on user roles) I would require to have some functionality, that exposes the available modules to my application. Something like

```js
Modeler.modules() // list all module names

Modeler.addModule(name) // adds this module

Modeler.removeModule(name) // removes this module
```

I have searched to code of the `bpmn-js` repo so far but found no properties / methods / API that expose these modules.

I just found a way to search the directory of the node module in order to get the desired folders (`/lib/*`) but that seems very odd to me, since this structure might change with the next version due to refactoring, redesign etc.

Am I really stuck to write my own implementation or did somebody successfully solve this already? (Any "hidden" properties that implicitly expose the available modules?)

Comment: Your question is about getting the list of possible modules or adding them at run-time?

Comment: Actually both. If the folder structure changes (which happened latetly in bpmn-js) it crashes all my depending code and refactoring also makes no sense if not having any property exposure but using import paths :-/ Edit: I just think that digging in the node_modules folder at runtime feels like a no-no.